# Count the number of approximate string matches in text corpus using fuzzy matching

Tags: python, string-matching, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying to find the number of times a string appears in a long text. When there is no exact match, I want to use fuzzy partial matching to find out whether the target string partially matches a substring in the text corpus. So far, this is what I have:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
# Target name and text corpus
target_name = 'Example Company S.A.'
text = '''This is an example text, containing various
words around the company
name I actually want to find. This name is Example
company SA, and as you can
see this will not return an exact match. Here is the
name again with some modifications: example company.'''
# Get number of exact matches
n_matches = text.count(target_name)  # This is 0
# Score for fuzzy matching after tokenization
fuzz.partial_token_set_ratio(target_name, text)  # This is 100
```

My question is: is there any way to count the number of times this fuzzy matching finds the target name (after setting a score threshold, i.e. 85) within the text corpus? I am pretty new to this kind of techniques and I have not found any example doing exactly this.

Comment: First of all you should set a threshold...

Comment: Yes you are right, I forgot to mention that but obviously the count should consider a treshold, I edited the post including such specification, thank you.